# Invoking remote command/script with specific credentials

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, copy

I am attempting to invoke a remote batch script using powershell.

Here is some sample code:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 127.0.0.1 {C:\myfile.bat}
```

myfile.bat contains this:

```
echo %USERNAME%
copy \\10.10.10.10\sample c:\toMe
```

When I invoke the myFile.bat locally in a cmd window, everything is fine. My username is expected. However, when I run the Invoke-Command using powershell, it gives me this error, while the username is still correct:

```
Access is denied.
```

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "MyPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$username = "Domain\Username"
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 127.0.0.1 {myfile.bat} -credential $cred
```

However, while this equates to the same username, it still gives me the same error.

I then tried to create a PSDrive, and execute the command as well:

```
New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\10.10.10.10\sample
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 127.0.0.1 {myfile.bat}
Remove-PSDrive X
```

But I also get the same error. I am now completely stumped. Without changing the batch script, what can I do in powershell to make it fulfill this request?

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?

```
$password='p@ssword'|convertto-securestring -asplaintext -force;
$cred=new-object -typename system.management.automation.pscredential('Domain\Username',$password);
Invoke-Command -computer 127.0.0.1 {c:\myfile.bat} -credential $cred;
```

or

```
$password='p@ssword'|convertto-securestring -asplaintext -force;
$cred=new-object -typename system.management.automation.pscredential('Domain\Username',$password);
$s = New-PSSession -computer "127.0.0.1" -credential $cred;
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { cmd /c "c:\myfile.bat" };
Remove-PSSession $s;
```

also, you may test changing `domain\username` with `username`